# Read a different file in package.json file in NodeJS

Tags: reactjs, node.js

I am learning NodeJS and created multiple microservices. Where each microservice handles different functionality. Now my question here is, I have 4 micro services and each service has their own package.json file and its dependencies. I need to maintain the the dependencies versions across all the microservice. For example, today I created a service with `lodash` version as `1.0.0` and after a month I created another service and installed the `lodash` but this time the version could be `1.0.1`. So in between these two projects I have two different versions of `lodash`. How should I maintain the same version across all the services/projects that I created. I can't check each and every service every time for the versions.

Can anyone please point me to the right direction how to solve this problem.?

I am basically a JAVA developer and in my previous company we created a separate service to maintain all the dependencies and used that project as a parent project in Maven. So if we change the dependencies version in that service it effects to all the projects.

I saw the same kind of a thing in RubyOnRails where it has a `eval_gemfile` command to achieve this.

But I haven't find how to achieve this in NodeJS.

I need to achieve how to maintain all the dependency versions across all the microservices. If I wanna update that version in one place it needs to effect all the services and sometimes we can override that version as well.

Answer (score 0):

In Node.js, you can achieve similar dependency management across multiple microservices using a tool like **Yarn Workspaces** or **npm workspaces**.

Workspaces allow managing multiple packages in a single **top-level**, root project. Each microservice can be a *separate package* within the workspace, and you can share dependencies and manage their versions more easily.

To create a new workspace, you just need to add the `workspaces` field in your root package.json file:

```
{
  "workspaces": [
    "microservice1",
    "microservice2",
    "microservice3",
    "microservice4"
  ]
}
```

You can find a more in-depth explanation in the official documentation: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/workspaces